# Storing Cartesian points in a vector and outputting distance

Tags: c++, c++11

Im having trouble writing my main for a class I created. I created a class called CartesianPoints which I want to use to construct my main with. I have the general structure of my main created but am struggling with the some technical stuff..

Heres what im looking for:

- creating an empty vector of CartesianPoint Objects which will be the starting point for the vector
- Limit range for x and y values between 10 & -10.
- loop to show user the points they just entered and ask what they would like to enter next
- the loop above should continue until the break is triggered

here is my header for CartesianPoints

```
    #ifndef MY_CARTESIAN_POINT_H

    #define MY_CARTESIAN_POINT_H

    #include <iostream>         // cin, cout
    #include <sstream>          // stringstream
    #include <cmath>            // sqrt()
    #include <limits>           // INT_MAX
    #include <stdexcept>        // out_of_range

    using namespace std;


    class CartesianPoint
    {
      public:

        CartesianPoint(int x = 1, int y = 1) { SetPoint(x, y); }


        int GetX() const { return myX; }
        int GetY() const { return myY; } 


        double GetDistanceTo(CartesianPoint pointTo) const; 
        string ToString() const;    


        void SetX(int x) { myX = validateCoordinateValue(x); } 
        void SetY(int y) { myY = validateCoordinateValue(y); } 
        void SetPoint(int x, int y) { SetX(x); SetY(y); }   

        static int GetLimit() { return sharedLimit; }

        static void SetLimit(int limit) { sharedLimit = abs(limit); }

      private: 

        int myX; 
        int myY;  


        static int sharedLimit; 


        int validateCoordinateValue(int value) const;

    };  

    int CartesianPoint::sharedLimit = INT_MAX;    

    double CartesianPoint::GetDistanceTo(CartesianPoint pointTo) const 
    {
        int xDelta = pointTo.myX - myX; 
        int yDelta = pointTo.myY - myY;

        return sqrt((xDelta * xDelta) + (yDelta * yDelta));
    } 

    string CartesianPoint::ToString() const
    {

        stringstream strOut; 

        strOut << "(" << myX << ", " << myY << ")";

        return strOut.str();
    }

    int CartesianPoint::validateCoordinateValue(int value) const
    {

        if((value < -sharedLimit || value > sharedLimit))
        {

            throw out_of_range( "Parameter (" + to_string(value) + ") must be between " 
                + to_string(-sharedLimit) + " and " + to_string(sharedLimit) + ".");
        }
        return value;
    }

    #endif
```

here is my main so far

```
int main()
{

GreetingScreen(); // just a formatting function ive already created 

// while loop that makes will give the option to end the program.
while(/* if myX! =10 and myY!= 10 keep doing this loop */ )
{
    // try catch for errors....
    try
    {
        cout << "Move from point"  /* (0,0)*/ "to where?" << endl;  
        cout << "X: " << endl;
        cin >> x; //point x 
        cout << "Y: " << endl; 
        cin >> y; //point y 


        catch 
        {
            cerr << "could not do this task"; 
        }

    } 
} // ending of while loop 
} // ending of main
```

Comment: This won't even compile... catch requires an argument (in parentheses), at least an ellipsis. In the given case, though, it is in vain anyway, as neither `operator<<` nor `operator>>` actually throw. You need to check the stream state instead to know if something went wrong. `while(x != 10 && y != 10)`, provided you define x and y before the loop and initialise at least one with a value != 10 (the other one can have arbitrary value, but must be initialised, too, to prevent undefined behaviour), otherwise the loop won't ever be entered.

Comment: Pick one of the four problems you are having and remove the other three from the question or risk the question being deemed too broad and closed. Suggestion: Pick the problem you need earliest.

Comment: Please read about how to write a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `std::vector`'s default constructor leaves the vector empty anyway, so you just write `std::vector<CartesianPoint> points;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, but there are a few things that I do see a concern with.

- In your class I don't see where you are using `<iostream>` I think you can omit it.
- You are using `using namespace std`. It is preferred to just scope out the namespace `std::`.
- About your constructor:

  > ```
  > CartesianPoint(int x = 1, int y = 1) { SetPoint(x, y); }
  > ```

Here you have two default values, there are two options here:

- Declare this constructor as `explicit`

  > ```
  > explicit CartesianPoint( int x = 1, int y = 1 ) { SetPoint( x, y ); }
  > ```
- Declare a default and user defined constructors

  > ```
  > CartesianPoint() { SetPoint( x, y ); }
  >
  > CartesianPoint( int x, int y ) { SetPoint( x, y ); } // by value
  >
  > CartesianPoint( int& x, int& y ) { SetPoint( x, y ); } // by reference
  > ```

*Note* - The third constructor my require overloads for the SetPoint function to accept by reference, however if you continue reading below you will see what I've done with your class.

Personally I think the 2<sup>nd</sup> choice is the better of the two. If you choose to use a constructor with 2 parameters and both have default values and you are not declaring the constructor as explicit; you will run into trouble.

This is why I preferably choose to use the 2<sup>nd</sup> option of declaring both a default constructor and a user defined constructor. This gives you the flexibility to do any of the following:

```
{
     CartesianPoint p1;  // default constructor called
     CartesianPoint p2( 5, 6 ); // user defined constructor called.
     int x = 5;
     int y = 6;
     CartesianPoint p3( x, y ); // another user defined constructor called.
}
```

Now there is something else with the constructor: you are calling a member function to set the point `(x,y)` This is not really needed. Class's have a member initializer list; use them! You are also using member functions `SetX()` and `SetY()` in your member function `SetPoint()` the extra calls are not needed.

---

Personally I would write your class as such:

```
#ifndef MY_CARTESIAN_POINT_H
#define MY_CARTESIAN_POINT_H

// #include <iostream>      // cin, cout
#include <sstream>          // stringstream
#include <cmath>            // sqrt()
#include <limits>           // INT_MAX
#include <stdexcept>        // out_of_range

// using namespace std;

class CartesianPoint {
private:
    int myX;
    int myY;

    static int sharedLimit;
public:

    CartesianPoint() : myX( 0 ), myY( 0 ) {} // I chose 0, but you can choose any default values for (x,y)
    CartesianPoint( int x, int y ) : 
        myX( validate( x ) ), 
        myY( validate( y ) ) {
    }
    CartesianPoint( int& x, int& y ) :
        myX( validate( x ) ),
        myY( validate( y ) ) {
    }

    int GetX() const { return myX; }
    int GetY() const { return myY; } 

    // by value
    void SetX(int x) { myX = validate(x); } 
    void SetY(int y) { myY = validate(y); } 
    void SetPoint(int x, int y) { 
        myX = validate( x );
        myY = validate( y );
    }

    // by reference
    void SetX( int& x ) { myX = validate(x); }
    void SetY( int& y ) { myX = validate(y); }
    void SetPoint( int& x, int& y ) {
        myX = validate( x );
        myY = validate( y );
    }

    double GetDistanceTo(CartesianPoint pointTo) const; 
    string ToString() const;

    static int GetLimit() { return sharedLimit; }
    static void SetLimit(int limit) { sharedLimit = abs(limit); }

  private:
    int validate( int value ) const;   // by value
    int validate( int& value ) const;  // by reference
};  

int CartesianPoint::sharedLimit = INT_MAX;    

double CartesianPoint::GetDistanceTo(CartesianPoint& pointTo) const  {
    int xDelta = pointTo.myX - myX; 
    int yDelta = pointTo.myY - myY;
    return sqrt((xDelta * xDelta) + (yDelta * yDelta));
} 

std::string CartesianPoint::ToString() const {
    std::stringstream strOut;
    strOut << "(" << myX << ", " << myY << ")";
    return strOut.str();
}

int CartesianPoint::validate(int value) const {
    return validate( value );
}

int CartesianPoint::validate( int& value ) const {
    if((value < -sharedLimit || value > sharedLimit)) {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << "Out Of Range: Parameter (" 
               << + ToString(value) 
               << + ") must be between " 
               << + ToString(-sharedLimit) 
               << + " and " 
               << + ToString(sharedLimit) 
               << + '.';                
        throw stream.str();
    }
    return value;
}


#endif
```

*`main.cpp`*

```
#include <iostream>   
#include "CartesianPoint.h"

int main() {
    try {
        std::vector<CartesianPoint> points; // It's already empty

        while( condition(s) ) {
            // do work
        }

    } catch( std::string& str ) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        return -1;          
    } catch( ... ) {
        std::cout << "Caught some other or unknown exception." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT** - I made a change to the `validateCoordinateValue` I first changed it's name to just `validate` for several reasons:

- 1<sup>st</sup>: It is a private method to the function and it isn't exposed as part of its public interface.
- 2<sup>nd</sup>: It is shorter and easier to type as well as read.
- 3<sup>rd</sup>: When using it in the class just as `validate()` it is already self explanatory of what the function does. Compare the two:

  - `myX = validateCoordinateValue( x );`
  - `myX = validate( x );`

Then I also added in an overload of the function to accept pass by reference as well. The reference version does the work, the pass by value function just simply returns and calls the reference version.

Comment: in my while loop in main function how would I call upon that vector for instance 
cout << "Move from point" << CartesianPoints() << " to where?" << endl;
which should initially print (0,0)

Comment: @ErikJackson Well if your vector is initially empty then you can not reference into the vector to retrieve a CartesianPoint and its members. You have to populate your vector, there are a few different ways to do this. You can initialize the vector with multiple objects within its initialize list, you can create an object and use push_back, you can use the vector's emplace_back and pass the required parameters.  Once you have the vector populated, then it's a matter of either traversing through it, using the index[] operator or finding a specific match in the vector.

Comment: @ErikJackson ...continued; as to what you are asking about `cout << "Move from point" << CartesianPoints() << " to where?" << endl;` It is actually unclear of what you are asking.